# Programmatic UITextField not visible on viewDidLoad

Tags: swift, uitextfield

I am trying create a `UITextField` programmatically, however it does not appear in the view.

I believe I have set the constraints correctly and they should all be activated on `viewDidLoad`. I am sure I have missed something obvious however for the life of me cannot understand what.

```
class HomeController: UIViewController {

    let textField: UITextField = {
        let input = UITextField()
        input.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return input
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = .purple

        view.addSubview(textField)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            textField.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor),
            textField.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor),
            textField.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 300),
            textField.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40)
        ])

    }
}
```

Comment: What does you view look like now? Does the text field show up in the view hierarchy on your debugger?

Comment: What does it show if you print view.subviews? There is no text in the label. Are you sure it's not just an empty label showing up. You can also try tapping on the small icon that looks like a rectangle on top of a square on the bottom bar where the console is to see the layers. Or use the accessibility inspector.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set a background property and it will show.

```
let textField: UITextField = {
    let input = UITextField()
    input.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    input.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return input
}()
```

Comment: Yup; the label is probably there but there is no text so it seems like it isn't there.

Comment: Ah yes! I knew it was something silly! Perhaps writing code at 3am does not work as well I as I imagined :) Thank you so much.